# Export data table to Excel sheet

Tags: asp.net, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I want to export data from data table to Excel file. I need to save the file on server. I am using the console application for this project.

Comment: You are using a console application but you have tagged ASP.NET?

Comment: Almost all SQL packages have an Extract, Transform, Load (ETL) tool. Some of them can export directly to an Excel file. Which SQL flavor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned if excel is installed, i recommend [`EPPlus`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439) to create the excel file. It has a convenient method `LoadFromDataTable`:

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet-Name");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable1, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium1);
    using(var fileStream = File.Create(path))
        pck.SaveAs(fileStream);
}
```

**Edit** i've only just seen that you have tagged <kbd>export-to-csv</kbd>.

```
var lines = dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => string.Join(",", r.ItemArray));
string csv = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);

File.AppendAllText(path, csv);
```

Comment: I have one question, how I can format my generated Excel sheet from above code. Please help me.

Comment: @Mahesh: CSV has never a _format_. It is a comma separated list of string values, no more, no less. If you want format you need to create an excel sheet, for example by using `EPPlus` as i've shown above.

Comment: Dear Tim, I never forgot you help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DtReqDetails != null)
 {
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=History.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dc in DtReqDetails.Columns)
    {
      Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
      tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    int i;
    foreach (DataRow dr in DtReqDetails.Rows)
   {
      tab = "";
      for (i = 0; i < DtReqDetails.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
        Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
        tab = "\t";
       }
       Response.Write("\n");
   }
   Response.End();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL, then they have a built-in [procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) for exporting a table to an Excel spreadsheet. No coding required.